# Trying to make a make a loan calculator, Can not find symbols

Tags: java, variables, calculator, symbols

I've searched all of google and here and can't figure out why my calculator isn't working. It seems that all of my variables and doubles are declared and called on at some point but it keeps saying "Can not find symbol." This applies to variables P, Y, and R. Can someone please help? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carloan {
   public static void main(String[] args){

      int r = R / 1200;
      double n = 12 * Y;        
      double payment  = (P * r) / (1 - Math.pow(1+r, -n));
      double interest = payment * n - P;
      int P;
      int Y;
      double R;

      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

      //double P;
      System.out.println("Enter loan amount: $" + P);

      P = input.nextInt();

      //double Y;
      System.out.println("Enter number of years: " + Y);

      Y = input.nextInt();

      //double R;
      System.out.println("Enter interest rate: %" + R);

      R = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Monthly payments = " + payment);
      System.out.println("Total interest   = " + interest);

   }
}
```

Comment: Your `double n = 12 * Y;` calls for an int Y that is not defined yet. So do `payment` and `interest`, which call for additional undefined variables. You might want to move the values for these to be calculated as methods, rather than on instantiation.

Comment: please move declarations `int P;` `double R;` and `int Y;` up: above their uses, so that they are declared before used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-examined the question and I noticed that you basically had written all the code out, it's just out of order. You want to move your declarations for r, n, payment, and interest down, since they are dependent on P, Y, and R. You also want to remove the `+ P` and `+ Y` and `+ R` sections as those don't print out anything meaningful.

I also went ahead and recast everything as a double since you commented that you wanted them as doubles. You can change them back to int if you want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Carloan {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        double P;
        double Y;
        double R;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        //double P;
        System.out.println("Enter loan amount: $");

        P = input.nextDouble();

        //double Y;
        System.out.println("Enter number of years: ");

        Y = input.nextDouble();

        //double R;
        System.out.println("Enter interest rate: %");

        R = input.nextDouble();

        //calculate all these values after you have P, Y, and R defined, not before
        double r = R / 1200;
        double n = 12 * Y;        
        double payment  = (P * r) / (1 - Math.pow(1+r, -n));
        double interest = payment * n - P;

        System.out.println("Monthly payments = " + payment);
        System.out.println("Total interest   = " + interest);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed. I tried moving the integers and doubles everywhere with no luck. This fixed my problem.

Comment: @MikeMivecNicolosi Yes, you have to make sure you use them in the order you want them. Normally, people keep all their variable declarations at the top so they can keep track of them. If you want to assign them values, you want to assign them after everything they need has been defined.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You use those variable before they are declared (in the declaration of the other variable)
2. Even if you moved the declarations of those variables *before* they are used, you still must initialize them before use (unlike fields, local variables do not get initialized to a default value if an initial value us not coded in the declaration).

It seems you believe that declaring a variable using an arithmetic expression will somehow keep the variable's value up to dare as the variable used in the expression change. This is not the case; arithmetic expressions are performed where coded only.

Answer (score 1):

You want to declare the variables and input values into them before using your equations. Also, you cannot use variables before giving them a value, like in the line: System.out.println("Enter loan amount: $" + P);

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int P, Y;
        double R;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter loan amount: $");
        P = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter number of years: ");
        Y = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter interest rate: %");
        R = input.nextDouble();

        double r = R / 1200;
        double n = 12 * Y;
        double payment  = (P * r) / (1 - Math.pow(1+r, -n));
        double interest = payment * n - P;

        System.out.println("Monthly payments = " + payment);
        System.out.println("Total interest   = " + interest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable before their declaration.
try with

```
int P;
int Y;
double R;

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

//double P;
System.out.println("Enter loan amount: $" + P);

P = input.nextInt();

//double Y;
System.out.println("Enter number of years: " + Y);

Y = input.nextInt();

//double R;
System.out.println("Enter interest rate: %" + R);

R = input.nextDouble();

int r = R / 1200;
double n = 12 * Y;        
double payment  = (P * r) / (1 - Math.pow(1+r, -n));
double interest = payment * n - P;
System.out.println("Monthly payments = " + payment);
System.out.println("Total interest   = " + interest);
```

Don't forget to cast R/1200 to int if you want it to be an int or just change the type of 'r' to double to become: double r = R / 1200;

Comment: Initialization need before use it in println: P, Y, R

Answer (score 0):

You need to define things before you use them.

The first thing you do is say `int r = R / 1200;` -- but what's R?  you've not declared it [yet -- I know that you declared `double R` later, but the compiler doesn't].

I would suggest making all your declarations without expressions: `int r;`, `double n`, and so on at the top, and then (after you get input from the user), doing the math at the bottom.

---

It looks to me like you have used some kind of mathematical language before; it is important to remember that in procedural languages (like java), statements are run line-by-line.  Something like `x=x+1` is a perfectly valid statement that makes `x` one larger than it was before that line.  `x=2; y=x/2; x=4;` will end with `y==1` and `x==4`, because the change in x doesn't carry back.

Additionally, integer arithmetic is a little tricky: division rounds down -- `5/2 = 2`, while `5.0/2.0 = 2.5`.  That might be a problem when you do `r=R/1200`, since `R` and `1200` are both integers.